# Secure Appveyor variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, appveyor, securestring

How to use a secure variable in a PowerShell command?

Example:

```
environment:
  password:
    secure: HEa8MAJyyfSv33snyK3Gleflk9SIfZBxbnTiS39hlWM=

install:
- ps: $env:password
```

Nothing is printed by this command.
According to [this page](http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/take-charge-environment-variables-powershell) this is the way to use environment variables in PowerShell but apparently the secure Appveyor variable is not there.

Comment: `get-item $env:password` can not return an error message about `path`?! Are you copy/pasting/editing your actual script/error message?

Comment: And you don't need `get-item` anyway. Just `$env:password` would do, assuming there's an environment variable `%password%` *(which I find odd in by itself...)*

Comment: I only changed the variable name from `pypipw` to `password`.

Comment: The environment variables for `cmd` and `Powershell` are the same so the only reason I can think of is that you've started `cmd` with another user then `Powershell` *(and have another environment)`. What does `set` in `cmd` return? What does `cd env:` and `gci`in `Powershell` return?

Comment: Nothing is returned when I try to print the secure variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit:

From the [Appveyor webpage about secure variables](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#secure-variables):

> secure variables are not decoded during Pull Request

That was exactly what I was trying to do.

As mentioned in the comments, secure variables can be activated in the Appveyor project settings and everything works as intended.

Comment: Right, but you can enable that with UI checkbox in General settings: `Enable secure variables in Pull Requests from the same repository only`  for public and private repos, and `Enable secure variables in all Pull Requests`  for private repos